# How to start Hazelcast without binding to any port?

Tags: sockets, hazelcast

Need to start Hazelcast as a singleton only for local testing of IMAP. So don't need to open any local ports. Is there a way to disable/stop Hazelcast from binding to local address ?

So far I have tried disabling Mulitcast/TCP. 
multicast enabled ="false"

Also tried the following config:
"port-auto-increment="false" -1 "/port "

But it still manages to pick a port and bind to it..

Picked Address[X.X.X.X]:51376, using socket ServerSocket[addr=/X.X.X.X,localport=**51376**], bind any local is false
[main] com.hazelcast.system  - [X.X.X.X]:51376 [dev] Hazelcast Community Edition **3.1.2** (20131120) starting at Address[X.X.X.X]:51376
[main] com.hazelcast.system  - [X.X.X.X]:51376 [dev] Copyright (C) 2008-2013 Hazelcast.com
[main] com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService  - [X.X.X.X]:51376 [dev] Address[X.X.X.X]:51376 is STARTING
[main] com.hazelcast.instance.Node  - [X.X.X.X]:51376 [dev] No join method is enabled! Starting standalone.
[main] com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService  - [X.X.X.X]]:51376 [dev] Address[X.X.X.X]]:51376 is STARTED

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is possible. A port is always needed for internal administration.

Comment: Was really hoping there was a config setting that can turn this off. Thanks for your quick reply.